# Edge Detection minimum line length?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to filter out short lines from my canny edge detection. Here's what I'm currently using as well as a brief explanation:

I start out by taking a single channel of the image and running CV2's Canny edge detection. Following that, I scan through each pixel and detect if there are any around it that are white (True, 255). If it is, I add it to a group of true pixels and then check every pixel around it (and keep looping until there are no white/True pixels left. I then replace all the pixels with black/False if the group count is less than a designated threshold (In this case, 100 pixels).

While this works (as shown below) it's awfully slow. I'm wondering if there's a faster, easier way to do this.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("edtest.jpg")
img_r = img.copy()
img_r[:, :, 0] = 0
img_r[:, :, 1] = 0
img_r = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_r, (3, 3), 0)
basic_edge = cv2.Canny(img_r, 240, 250)

culled_edge = basic_edge.copy()
min_threshold = 100

for x in range(len(culled_edge)):
    print(x)
    for y in range(len(culled_edge[x])):
        test_pixels = [(x, y)]
        true_pixels = [(x, y)]

        while len(test_pixels) != 0:

            xorigin = test_pixels[0][0]
            yorigin = test_pixels[0][1]
            if 0 < xorigin < len(culled_edge) - 1 and 0 < yorigin < len(culled_edge[0]) - 1:
                for testx in range(3):
                    for testy in range(3):
                        if culled_edge[xorigin-1+testx][yorigin - 1 + testy] == 255 and (xorigin-1+testx, yorigin-1+testy) not in true_pixels:
                            test_pixels.append((xorigin-1+testx, yorigin-1+testy))
                            true_pixels.append((xorigin-1+testx, yorigin-1+testy))
            test_pixels.pop(0)

        if 1 < len(true_pixels) < min_threshold:
            for i in range(len(true_pixels)):
                culled_edge[true_pixels[i][0]][true_pixels[i][1]] = 0

cv2.imshow("basic_edge", basic_edge)
cv2.imshow("culled_edge", culled_edge)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Source Image:

[image: Source Image]

Canny Detection and Filtered (Ideal) Results:
[image]

Comment: You can get contours of your edges and then filter on contour area or perimeter. You can also use connectedComponentsWithStats() and filter on area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you are applying is called an area opening. I don't think there is an implementation in OpenCV, but you can find one in either scikit-image ([`skimage.morphology.area_opening`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.area_opening)) or DIPlib ([`dip.BinaryAreaOpening`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-BinaryAreaOpening-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-uint--dip-String-CL)).

For example with DIPlib (disclosure: I'm an author) you'd amend your code as follows:

```py
import diplib as dip

# ...
basic_edge = cv2.Canny(img_r, 240, 250)
min_threshold = 100
culled_edge = dip.BinaryAreaOpening(basic_edge > 0, min_threshold)
```

The output, `culled_edge`, is now a `dip.Image` object, which is compatible with NumPy arrays and you should be able to use it as such in many situations. If there's an issue, then you can cast it back to a NumPy array with `culled_edge = np.array(culled_edge)`.